# angular routing with ng-include

Tags: angularjs, routes, angularjs-routing, angular-promise, angularjs-http

It's a little complex to describe my problem.Now I have two pages to be routed. One is **project.jsp**,the other is **ticket.jsp**.The latter can be included in the former using ng-include.

In index.jsp,I use ng-view.

index.jsp

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

In app.js,I do the routing config and create controllers.

```
$routeProvider.when('/tickets', {
    templateUrl: 'ticket.jsp',
    controller: 'ticketController',
    resolve:{
        data:function($http) {
        return $http.get('xxxxx').then(function(d){
            //success
            return d;
        },function(){
            //failure
        });
        }
    }
    }).when('/projects', {
    templateUrl: 'project.jsp',
    controller: 'projectController',
    resolve:{
        data:function($http) {
        return $http.get('xxxxx').then(function(d){
            //success
            return d;
        },function(){
            //failure
        });
        }
    }
    })


  app.controller('projectController', function($scope,data)
  {
        $scope.tickets=data.data;
  });
 app.controller('ticketController', function($scope,data)
  {
        if(data)
           $scope.tickets=data.data;
  });
```

project.jsp

```
<div ng-include="'ticket.jsp'" ng-controller="ticketController"></div>
```

ticket.jsp

```
<div>{{tickets}}</div>
```

Now,here is the problem.In both of the controllers,I have to inject the **data** but when the view is project.jsp,I have to declare ticketController in ng-include,which will cause **unknown provider** because I inject "data".If I don't declare it in ng-include,I can't use the controller.If I don't inject "data",I can't access data when the current view is ticket.jsp.I'm really confused.How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Use a services to get the data, then have both the controllers access the services. I believe what you are doing is very restrictive!

Comment: Thanks for your help.You are right that I should use service.You means I move the code in resolve to controller in a sense?@CallumLinington

Comment: Yeah exactly, so the service can be a singleton as well so you don't have to make requests if you already have the data, but then its up to you how you want to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Callum Linington Said you create one singleton service and maintain data there.

```
app.service('sharedData', function($q, $http){
    this.data = {};
    this.getData = function(url){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(url).then(function(d){
            //success
            this.data = d;
            deferred.resolve(d);
        },function(){
            //failure
            deferred.reject(d);
        });
       return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('projectController', function($scope, sharedData) {
    var url = 'http://example.com/project/get?param1=1&param2=2'
    if (sharedData.data.length <= 0) { //check does data exist
        //no then make a call to get data
        sharedData.getData(url).then(function(data) {
            //assign data
            $scope.tickets = data; //or $scope.tickets = sharedData.data
        });
    } else {
        $scope.tickets = sharedData.data; //yes then assign data directly
    }
});

app.controller('ticketController', function($scope, sharedData) {
    var url = 'http://example.com/ticket/get?param1=1&param2=2'
    if (sharedData.data.length <= 0) { //check does data exist
        //no then make a call to get data
        sharedData.getData(url).then(function(data) {
            //assign data
            $scope.tickets = data; //or $scope.tickets = sharedData.data
        });
    } else {
        $scope.tickets = sharedData.data; //yes then assign data directly
    }
});
```

Use above code. May help you. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I am really new to it,so it's a little hard for me to understand
your code in controller.It seems `sharedData.data` ={} when not using then().why? And what if my $http request have a param? `$http.get('the url with param')`

Comment: @lionel thats my bad, there were couple of mistake, i've updated my code. please check it.

Comment: You're so kind.I had a try in my project.I got an error that "can't get property then of undefined."  I found that sharedData.getData(url) return undefined.What's wrong?@pankajparkar

Comment: @lionel Now i changed my code again added `return deferred.promise;` which was missing inside service code..Now code will work proper because  previously code was not returning any promise..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-view for your common routing (means where routing happens rapidly).

If you have utilized ng-view already then go for ng-switch for second one.

Comment: how can using `ng-view` or `ng-switch` will persist data?